# Странный результат на выходе нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети

Есть у меня двухслойная нейронная сеть с 625 входами и 6 выходами.

```
AMOUNT_NEURONS = 6;

net = newff(range,[2*AMOUNT_NEURONS AMOUNT_NEURONS]);
net = init(net);
net = train(net,x, y);
```

`range` - это матрица 625x2 для задания диапазона от 0 до 1

`x` - это матрица 625x180 с обучающей выборкой

`y` - это матрица 6x180 с правильными значениями для обучающей выборки. Она представляет собой 180 столбцов с нулями и одной единицей в строке, соответствующей правильному нейрону.

Я обучаю сеть (среднее квадратичное отклонение стремится к нулю) и пытаюсь ее протестировать

```
sim(net, vec)' %где vec - один из входных векторов обучающей выборки
```

Я надеялся получить вектор из нулей с одной единицей напротив правильного выходного нейрона, но получаю примерно следующее:

```
ans =
   -1.0000    1.0000   -0.7410   -0.9956    0.9990    0.9993
```

Почему получается такой результат? Откуда вообще вылезли отрицательные числа и почему вообще все числа по модулю стремятся к единице? Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению репутация не позволяет писать комменты, поэтому напишу неполный (пока) ответ.

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/01/neural-network-data-normalization-and-encoding.aspx

Здесь есть ценный набор рекомендаций по кодированию и нормализации данных для *НС*.

Так, например, в Вашем случае по видимому лучше кодировать **[0,1]** как **[-1,1]**.
В приведённой выше статье этот случай описан как `кодирование независимых бинарных данных`.

Answer (score 0):

Сеть возвращает вероятность на выходных нейронах, пропусти эти вероятности через функцию [image: введите сюда описание изображения], где t пороговое значение, например 0,5. Тогда будут результаты 0 или 1.